# Agrupar datos repetidos con un campo diferente y que se muestre una sola vez sin eliminar

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo la siguiente consulta me agrupa los resultados que son iguales, pero tengo un caso en particular.

```
SELECT T1.RFCSAT, T1.NumEmpleadoSAT, t1.NumSeguridadSocialSAT, 
   t1.CURPSAT, t1.RazonSocialSAT
 FROM DBENC60 t1
  LEFT JOIN eEmployee t2
    ON t2.RFC = t1.RFCSAT
 WHERE t2.RFC IS NULL and t1.RazonSocialSAT like '%brasil%' 
GROUP BY T1.RFCSAT, T1.NumEmpleadoSAT, t1.NumSeguridadSocialSAT, t1.CURPSAT, 
t1.RazonSocialSAT
order by  t1.RFCSAT ASC

RFC             No emple   segSocia      CURP                RAZON SOCIAL

ZUCB870411BK2   0111252    43907752920  ZUCB770441HNLXLR05  ZUNIGA GRAMACO BRAL
ZUCB870411BK2   0111252    43907752920  ZUCB770441HNLXLR05  ZUNIGA GRAMACO BRAL IGNACIO
```

Lo anterior es el resultado de mi consulta, y como se puede observar todos los campos se repiten excepto la razon social. Obviamente se que si quito t1.RazonSocialSAT me va mostrar un solo registro ya que todos los 4 campos se repiten. Pero yo quiero que aparezca la razon social de igual manera. Pero solo una vez, es decir que el que tiene el nombre completo le agredeceria si pudieran ayudarme

NOTA: NO SE PUEDEN ELIMINAR LOS REGISTRO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selecciona el `MAX()` del campo `t1.RazonSocialSAT`

```
SELECT 
     T1.RFCSAT, T1.NumEmpleadoSAT, t1.NumSeguridadSocialSAT, t1.CURPSAT,
     MAX(t1.RazonSocialSAT) as RazonSocialSAT
FROM DBENC60 t1
LEFT JOIN eEmployee t2 ON t2.RFC = t1.RFCSAT
WHERE t2.RFC IS NULL and t1.RazonSocialSAT like '%brasil%' 
GROUP BY T1.RFCSAT, T1.NumEmpleadoSAT, t1.NumSeguridadSocialSAT, t1.CURPSAT
ORDER BY  t1.RFCSAT ASC
```

Comment: Ya lo he intentado de esa manera pero no he tenido exito. me sigue arrojando los mismso resultados, ya que devuelve un valor de tipo cadena

Comment: Ya actualicé la respuesta. Solo quita el campo `t1.RazonSocialSAT` del `group by`

Comment: Ya quedo, si era eso lo que estaba causando problemas. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

el problema lo esta causando la tabla **(t1)->DBENC60**

en esta tabla debe existir un registro duplicado con el mismo

```
(t1.NumSeguridadSocialSAT, t1.CURPSAT)
```

pero diferente

```
t1.RazonSocialSAT
```

debes depurar la base o tener id Unico